# Magento Product

Tags: product

Suppose i have product shirt with attachable collar:

user can get collar of different colors:

Suppose For Shirt A(price 10) user have collar c1(price 1) , c2(price 3) ,c3(price 5) ,c4(price 2)
user can buy 5 qty of collar c1 , 2 qty of collar c2 
total price of product =10+5+6=21

and show them as single product of price 21.

How can i implement it in magento

Comment: you have to use the concept of bundle product

Comment: yeah but fro bundled product there is no option to choose separate qty for each bundled items

Comment: then you can use configurable product

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to setup bundle product for this requirement. here is link how to setup bundle product.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product

Comment: yeah but fro bundled product there is no option to choose separate qty for each bundled items

Comment: Please see the document.at the end it say's "Items can have either a preset or user-defined quantity".

Comment: got it thanks , can i show images also there ??